# Flutter PageView inside SingleChildScrollView block vertical scroll

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-pageview

I have a horizontal scrolling PageView inside vertical scrolling SingleChildScrollView

```
  Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  _buildItemImage(),
                   PageView.builder(
                     dragStartBehavior: widget.dragStartBehavior,
                     key: ValueKey<DateTime>(widget.selectedDate),
                     controller: widget.DiDidayPickerController,
                     physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                     scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                     itemCount: _monthDelta(widget.firstDate, widget.lastDate) + 1,
                     itemBuilder: _buildItems,
                     onPageChanged: _handleMonthPageChanged,
            )...
```

The problem is when I trying to scroll vertically in the area of PageView it intercepts the scroll event and doesn't let to scroll SingleChildScrollView. How to fix it?

[image]